# .Net Memory Management Issue : Objects Stuck in Generation 2

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory-management

I have profiled my App w/ VS2010 profiler, with object lifetime collection enabled.
I was heavilly surprised to see that most instances of a particular struct named "Record" are collected by the GC as Gen 2 instances. I am very upset, as instances of "Record" struct should live less than 500ms each (theoretically).

These structs are simple time series data of 6xInt32 or so, that are read on the flow, Queued/Dequeued in a Queue having a size of 1000, passed to a processor that fires some logic depending on those few millions "Records" sequentially. I do not need to keep more than 50 records at a time.

So my question is : Why could these object live long enough to mainly end up as Second Generation references, and what could I do to ensure they REALLY get dumped off after each computation.

***EDIT :*** 
I am asking this because I have noticed a drastic performance dropdown for bigger sample sizes (i.e Records Numbers) : if N take T minutes, 2N takes 2,5T minutes or so, and so on.
 So there is obviously a leak somewhere.

***EDIT 2 :*** 
My Bad : Creating a struct instance cannot cause a garbage collection
I've changed it to classes and did not notice any significant improvement so far.
I'll run the profiler again with classes this time not structs) and see what it gives

***EDIT 3 :*** 
Many answers suspect Boxing/Unboxing to take place somewhere.
I DO use typed generic collections and typed Queues. And "Records" are never attached to any class as members. They are individually handled by events.
The ex-Struct (Now Class) implemented an interface and was casted by it when called (this is rather common usage) and I dropped off that interface. No improvement.

***EDIT 4 :*** 
I have run again the profiler, replacing struct by class. I have the same results : 
**most  instances of *CLASS* "Record" still end up being collected as Gen2 instances**

***EDIT 5 :*** 
Producers of the Record classes are many parallel **BackGroundWorkers** (Byte Readers), and there is one Consumer Thread that dispatches the Records to other methods after performing a few checks. Besides I use **Events and Delegates** to communicate between the different parts. I do not unregister those events because they are useful all along the process (I may be wrong on that point)

Comment: do you observe any degradation in performance that you can connect to the record being in gen2? If not why are you worried about how the GC is doing its business?

Comment: Are they STRUCTS? Not CLASSES?

Comment: @xanatos : If they were classes, I would've wrote "classes" :-)

Comment: @Henk : Why everybody keeps talking about classes. I've referred only to structs... ?

Comment: Still  a lot of info missing. Is it a generic Queue or do you use Boxing?  How is the Queue used? Better add some code samples.

Comment: @Mika: Using structs could be part of the problem. It's not the most logical design.

Comment: @Mika A) half the time what it's written in a question is only slightly similar to reality, B) and I thought that structs, unless put as a field of a class, didn't normally go to the heap (and so weren't GC collected) in the "standard" implementation of the .NET Fram. and C) At 6x4 bytes of struct, you are beyond the "standard" "good" limit of a struct.

Comment: On the "why" you are beyond the good limit: each time you insert your struct in a Queue<T> (are you using a generic collection, or are you boxing in an old-fashioned collection?), the struct is copied (so 24 bytes are read and written). Every time the struct is dequeued, it is read and written in a local variable (24 bytes). Every time a function receive the struct as a param, 24 bytes are read and copied. This is why structs should be small! (let's say no more than 4 sizeof(ptr), so the GUID on 32bit systems is the max size of a good struct). The interpreter COULD optimize. COULD, not SHOULD!

Comment: @xanatos : Oh... really was not aware of that :/ ... I am using a list typed with the struct. So... I've turned the Struct into Class (that was legacy code) and noticed a slight performance improvement. But it seems I am still stuck with the same timely issue... If you have other useful hints post an answer and put your previous comments in it, I think this could really help

Comment: Is your app single-threaded or multi-threaded? Or at least, are the producers and the consumers in the same thread?

Comment: @xanatos : Nope : Producers are many parallel BackGroundWorkers, and there is one Consumer Thread that dispatches the Records to other methods after performing a few checks.

Comment: If you have truly many BackgroundWorkers (lets say > 50), there is a general slowing of the GC (because the GC has to stop all the threads, to his work and then restart the thread)

Comment: @xana, there is no interpreter involved.

Comment: @mika: there are many reasons this could happen, and many solutions. You don't provide enough information to get real help. We're left guessing and you only get guesses.

Comment: @Henk : Be a little bit compassionate here, I am new to all this, it is Saturday Night, and I'm stuck alone with my computer at the 18th Floor of A corporate Building. I'll do my best to give all info I have when it occurs to me that it is relevant.

Comment: @Xana : I have 10 to 15 Workers

Comment: @mika: all the more reason to write a good question: include parts of the code. Declaration and usage of the Queue and "Record" would be the minimum.

Comment: @Henk : My code would quite basically be close to what I've described (Struct, Queues, Workers). I mean, I'm dealing with a big framework, I cant just post the code bits, I thought that  explaining it would be clearer. But, Ok, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you stored them just as local variables (which may or may not be possible depending on your scenario) they will never end up on the heap at all.

If that's possible, I recommend trying that. You might get a more in depth response, if you post a code sample.

As a sanity check, are you forgetting to unregister static events, or using some other class that may be doing this (some classes fix this via Dispose)?

Also have you looked into the possibility of using the [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)?

**Edit-** Since you now say you are doing something with events, this is highly likely to be a cause of your issues. Are you forgetting to unregister the events?

Comment: Uh ? Are you sure ? Why would local variables end up in Gen 2 ? I thought on the contrary that the fact that they are local (declared into methods) would "free" them from being referenced "ad vitam aeternam"...

Comment: If they are structs as you say they and they are local variables they will live on the stack.

Comment: Don't box and don't have them stored as member variables. It now sounds like the whole struct thing is not the issue, unless there are performance issues related to passing the struct around.

Comment: Where would the Boxing/Unboxing take place ? My Queue is typed... ?

Comment: That's a good question. I didn't say it was taking place, but it might be... One possible example- if your struct implements an interface and you treat the struct as that interface then that can be one cause of a box operation. You could use ildasm to look at boxing operations if you were concerned about them.

Comment: "if your struct implements an interface and you treat the struct as that interface then that can be one cause of a box operation". RIGHT ON ! DO you have a crystal ball ??? :-D I'll -try- drop off that interface and see what it does...

Comment: @Richard : Unfortunately, getting rid of the Interface did not improve performance (though avoiding extensive casting)

Comment: OK. Continueing the guess work- what about the event registration?

Comment: @Richard : This is a big framework here (I did not code the core). It's heavilly event based and events are designed to stay up an running through the whole process, like listeners. Does passing an object through an event results necessarily in it still being referenced ? Anyway I'm still digging this and thank you for the commitment and precious help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are "heavy" on memory use, and you are using C# 4.0, you could try the "server" GC. Merge your app.config (or web.config) with:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

(with merge I mean that if you already have some of these sections, use them, otherwhise create them. "configuration" is the first level element of the app.config). This is better for some apps (apps that don't need heavy interaction with the user)

Answer (score 0):

They end up as Second Generation because the GC just decided not to garbage collect them. I don't think it is really a problem to worry about.  If you really wanted to  you could just reuse the 1000 objects instead of continuously creating new ones.  This would make it so that these objects wouldn't need to get garbage collected.  You could force Garbage collection to ensure the objects "REALLY" get dumped but that would degrade performance as GC is an expensive operation or so I am told.

Comment: It's a little more involved than the GC saying, "I don't think I'll collect these objects today." They weren't collected because there are still references to them, or they're used in long lived objects.  You want a few objects as possible to live in the 2nd Generation.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to avoid an explicit call to GC.Collect. But it IS actually a problem to worry about as I have Millions of them and my computing ends up running slower and slower. I will try not to call the "new" keyword and just do a members update of existing objects (but that may be spooky to achieve)

Comment: @George : Yes you are absolutely right. Collection is not Random. That's why I would like to find a way to kill pending references to those objects.